# Paperback involving a ship with AI (personable) that gains the ability to jump (FTL) with other ships in close proximity, unlike the rest

Tags: story-identification, novel, space, artificial-intelligence

Paperback, ~1980-2010.

Human universe, galactic society, many factions, many 'almost' at war with one another. A single smaller ship has a ship mind that develops into a personality; it gains a human friend and also gains the ability to jump (FTL) with other ships in close proximity, something that no others can do when jumping.

Also involves finding a 'junk yard' of ancient warships and a warning about 'bad guys' that killed the old owners and are coming to scour any other races.

Comment: In what sense of the word was the ship's AI "personable"? Was it "Pleasing in appearance; good-looking; presentable" or was it "Pleasing in manner or behaviour; likeable; agreeable" or both? (Definitions quoted from the online OED.)

Answer (score 5):

Some elements of similarity with Consider Phlebas by Iain M Banks but I don't think it's what you're looking for

- Human (and other) universe at war
- Ship mind that performed a manoeuvre never previously achieved, in
  this case travelling through hyperspace to appear in a planet
- Warnings about death from an ascended elder species
- But no junk yard that I recall

For more information, see
[Why did the Idirans want the Mind in Consider Phlebas](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231935/why-did-the-idirans-want-the-mind-in-consider-phlebas). Particularly the quote from Xoralundra